# How should I put try/except in a single line?

Tags: python

Is there a way in python to turn a try/except into a single line?

something like...

```
b = 'some variable'
a = c | b #try statement goes here
```

Where `b` is a declared variable and `c` is not... so `c` would throw an error and `a` would become `b`...

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There is no way to compress a `try`/`except` block onto a single line in Python.

Also, it is a bad thing not to know whether a variable exists in Python, like you would in some other dynamic languages. The safer way (and the prevailing style) is to set all variables to something. If they might not get set, set them to `None` first (or `0` or `''` or something if it is more applicable.)

---

If you **do** assign all the names you are interested in first, you do have options.

- The best option is an if statement.

  ```
  c = None
  b = [1, 2]

  if c is None:
      a = b
  else:
      a = c
  ```
- The one-liner option is a conditional expression.

  ```
  c = None
  b = [1, 2]
  a = c if c is not None else b
  ```
- Some people abuse the short-circuiting behavior of `or` to do this. **This is error prone,** so I never use it.

  ```
  c = None
  b = [1, 2]
  a = c or b
  ```

  Consider the following case:

  ```
  c = []
  b = [1, 2]
  a = c or b
  ```

  In this case, `a` probably *should* be `[]`, but it is `[1, 2]` because `[]` is false in a boolean context. Because there are lots of values that can be false, I don't use the `or` trick. (This is the same problem people run into when they say `if foo:` when they mean `if foo is not None:`.)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that its actually a django model.objects.get query i am trying to test. the .get returns an error if no data is found... it doesn't return None (which annoys me)

Comment: @Brant, Okay, that situation is a bit different than checking if a variable is set (no variables are declared in Python). The typical style in Python is to prefer raising exceptions to returning errors as values, which many of us actually love. Having to check the return code of an operation every time and having a hard time tracking down errors if I don't is something I definitely don't miss about C when writing Python. In any event, though it's been discussed, there is no one-line syntax for a `try`/`except` block. Luckily lines are cheap, so the 4-line solution should work for you. ;-)

Comment: It is part of a large set of tuples within a dict... I was just trying to shorten things up a bit

Comment: Don't use `get` if you don't want an exception.  Use `filter` instead.

Comment: @MikeGraham Good answer - a hint (link?) why the short-circuiting is error prone would be nice.

Comment: @kratenko -- check out my example in the post

Comment: In python3, there is a way. See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52020518/2476373) of @dset0x below

Answer (score 126):

In python3 you can use [contextlib.suppress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress):

```
from contextlib import suppress

d = {}
with suppress(KeyError): d['foo']
```

Comment: this should be the standard answer

Comment: this answer don't solve the question. `suppress` just do `pass` on `except:` and here is no way to handle exception

Comment: Can we use suppress without giving any exeption type like `KeyError` and apply it for all exceptions?

Comment: @alper Yes, just use `Exception` if you want to catch generic exceptions like `KeyError` and `IndexError`, but `BaseException` if you want to catch `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt` and `GeneratorExit` as well (which you mostly don't care about)

Comment: So I have to use `Exception` and `BaseException` together to cover all the exceptions right? Something like: `with suppress(Exception, BaseException)` ?

Comment: @alper no, Exception is a "child" of BaseException. If you except BaseException you are handling every exception that exists

Comment: @Lysander12PT But I don't see `except BaseException as e:` in most solutions in stackoverflow; instead in all the examples I always see  `except Exception as e:`. Why than `Exception ` prefered over `BaseException `?

Comment: @alper Because `BaseException` also handles `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit` (exception that is called when using `sys.exit()`), etc. Handling those execeptions would make it impossible for you to exit your program unless you use the task manager or similar to force kill it.
Here's a video that explains it very well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrVfY9SuO64

Comment: Getting " KeyError: 'foo' " here.

Comment: for the above example `d.get('foo')` would be more appropriate

Answer (score 96):

This is terribly hackish, but I've used it at the prompt when I wanted to write up a sequence of actions for debugging:

```
exec "try: some_problematic_thing()\nexcept: problem=sys.exc_info()"
print "The problem is %s" % problem[1]
```

For the most part, I'm not at all bothered by the no-single-line-try-except restriction, but when I'm just experimenting and I want readline to recall a whole chunk of code at once in the interactive interpreter so that I can adjust it somehow, this little trick comes in handy.

For the actual purpose you are trying to accomplish, you might try `locals().get('c', b)`; ideally it would be better to use a real dictionary instead of the local context, or just assign c to None before running whatever may-or-may-not set it.

Comment: Hey, this answers the question! :)

Comment: Love this answer, super messy, but one line, just the way I like it.

Comment: This is the answer!!  will `problem[0]` return what that function returns?

Comment: Exec is a code smell and should be avoided unless nothing else works. If one line code is so important then this will work, but you need to ask yourself why one line is so important.

Comment: clearly not for production use, but exactly what is needed for an awkward debugging session.

Answer (score 26):

Version of poke53280 answer with limited expected exceptions.

```py
def try_or(func, default=None, expected_exc=(Exception,)):
    try:
        return func()
    except expected_exc:
        return default
```

and it could be used as

```py
In [2]: try_or(lambda: 1/2, default=float('nan'))
Out[2]: 0.5

In [3]: try_or(lambda: 1/0, default=float('nan'), expected_exc=(ArithmeticError,))
Out[3]: nan

In [4]: try_or(lambda: "1"/0, default=float('nan'), expected_exc=(ArithmeticError,))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
[your traceback here]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

In [5]: try_or(lambda: "1"/0, default=float('nan'), expected_exc=(ArithmeticError, TypeError))
Out[5]: nan
```

Comment: What is the comma in "expected_exc=(Exception,)" for? Can you explain, please?

Comment: @ibilgen The comma converts the expression to a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). Writing `(Exception)` is equal to leaving out the brackets. `(Exception, )` tells the interpreter that this is a tuple (something like a list) with one entry. In this example this is used so `expected_exc` can be more than one exception.

Comment: My favorite solution! Sometimes I need logging where I have to know a number of variables currently in scope, and I'm not given a stack trace and it's impossible to run the step debugger (like on a remote server). This allows me to see variables of interest in one line, so that I don't have to do a bunch of if statements, I can just use this one line with needed_variable = try_or(lambda : var_maybe_not_in_scope, default="none_present")

Answer (score 23):

Another way is to define a context manager:

```
class trialContextManager:
    def __enter__(self): pass
    def __exit__(self, *args): return True
trial = trialContextManager()
```

Then use the `with` statement to ignore errors in one single line:

```
>>> with trial: a = 5      # will be executed normally
>>> with trial: a = 1 / 0  # will be not executed and no exception is raised
>>> print a
5
```

No exception will be raised in case of a runtime error. It's like a `try:` without the `except:`.

Comment: This is great! Since there's no explicit try/except, could you explain briefly how the context manager deals with errors?

Comment: @Patrick see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35483461/412529 for how returning `True` from `__exit__` suppresses errors

Answer (score 14):

> The problem is that its actually a django model.objects.get query i am trying to test. the .get returns an error if no data is found... it doesn't return None (which annoys me)

Use something like this:

```
print("result:", try_or(lambda: model.objects.get(), '<n/a>'))
```

Where try_or is an utility function defined by you:

```
def try_or(fn, default):
    try:
        return fn()
    except:
        return default
```

Optionally you can restrict the accepted exception types to `NameError`, `AttributeError`, etc.

Comment: Interesting and nice approach! Suggestion: the `lambda` is pointless, just pass `model.objects.get` (without the `()` that performs a call) and it'll work as intended

Answer (score 13):

How about using two lines. is it ok ?

```
>>> try: a = 3; b= 0; c = a / b
... except : print('not possible'); print('zero division error')
...
not possible
zero division error
```

Answer (score 9):

Works on Python3, inspired by Walter Mundt

```
exec("try:some_problematic_thing()\nexcept:pass")
```

For mulitiples lines into one line

```
exec("try:\n\tprint('FirstLineOk')\n\tsome_problematic_thing()\n\tprint('ThirdLineNotTriggerd')\nexcept:pass")
```

Ps: Exec is unsafe to use on data you don't have control over.

Comment: Nice. I used this to check for a Python module: `python -c 'exec("try:import build\nexcept: exit(1)")'`

Answer (score 7):

```
parse_float = lambda x, y=exec("def f(s):\n try:\n  return float(s)\n except:  return None"): f(x)
```

There is always a solution.

Comment: Using `exec` 

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by accessing the namespace dict using `vars()`, `locals()`, or `globals()`, whichever is most appropriate for your situation.

```
>>> b = 'some variable'
>>> a = vars().get('c', b)
```

Comment: This doesn't work exactly the same as checking whether a variable is set (though it does if you are interested in a particular scope.) Also, ewwwwwwww.....

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that you're using django. If it makes sense for what you're doing you might want to use:

```
my_instance, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create()
```

`created` will be True or False. Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `with` syntax in one line:

```py
class OK(): __init__ = lambda self, *isok: setattr(self, 'isok', isok); __enter__ = lambda self: None; __exit__ = lambda self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback: (True if not self.isok or issubclass(exc_type, self.isok) else None) if exc_type else None
```

Ignore any errors:

```py
with OK(): 1/0
```

Ignore specified errors:

```py
with OK(ZeroDivisionError, NameError): 1/0
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to actually manage exceptions:
(modified from poke53280's answer)

```
>>> def try_or(fn, exceptions: dict = {}):
    try:
        return fn()
    except Exception as ei:
        for e in ei.__class__.__mro__[:-1]:
            if e in exceptions: return exceptions[e]()
        else:
            raise


>>> def context():
    return 1 + None

>>> try_or( context, {TypeError: lambda: print('TypeError exception')} )
TypeError exception
>>>
```

note that if the exception is not supported, it will raise as expected:

```
>>> try_or( context, {ValueError: lambda: print('ValueError exception')} )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#57>", line 1, in <module>
    try_or( context, {ValueError: lambda: print('ValueError exception')} )
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 3, in try_or
    return fn()
  File "<pyshell#56>", line 2, in context
    return 1 + None
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
>>>
```

also if `Exception` is given, it will match anything below.
(`BaseException` is higher, so it will not match)

```
>>> try_or( context, {Exception: lambda: print('exception')} )
exception
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler version of the answer provided by @surendra_ben

```py
a = "apple"
​
try: a.something_that_definitely_doesnt_exist
except: print("nope")

...

nope
```

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple examples here using try..except for handling dictionary keys. In those instances, the appropriate way would be to use the `.get` method which will return `None` when it is not available. Example

```
my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print(my_dict.get('c'))
# Output: None
```

Answer (score 0):

An actual clean oneliner that reads (somewhat) like the try-except block and is not super dirty would be as follows:

```
val = (lambda: dictionary["wrong key"]) % cept(KeyError) % (lambda: "default value")
```

This needs a setup like this

```
from infix import mod_infix

def cept(*args, as_exc=False):
    if not args:
        args = Exception

    @mod_infix
    def _cept(f1, f2):
        try:
            return f1()
        except args as e:
            if as_exc:
                return f2(e)
            else:
                return f2()
    return _cept
```

I wish I could do away with the lambdas, but there is no way.

I personally find the rejection notice for https://peps.python.org/pep-0463/ unsatisfying. Guido, if you are reading this (yea, I wish), please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

In case of this issue (original requested oneliner) you can resolve it by using ternary:

```py
a = c if 'c' in locals() else b
```