# Multiline script in a python command line argument

Tags: python

I am trying to invoke python from within an arch linux PKGBUILD script:

```
python -c "from module import func; func()"
```

The `func` raises an exception, which is expected behavior but causes the script to fail. 
Catching the exception like this does not work:

```
python -c "from module import func; try: func(); except ValueError: pass"
```

It seems there is no way to put try/except statements into a single line ([Python: try statement in a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2524853/3005167)).

Is there another way to ignore the exception or the fact that python returns with an error?
A solution that does not require additional scripts or other files would be most welcome :)

Comment: This is not about `try/except` but multiline in general; corrected the title :)

Comment: You are right of course. Thank you for editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in shell can contain embedded newlines:

```
python -c 'from module import func
try:
  func()
except ValueError:
  pass
'
```

Note that this presents a challenge if the Python to run contains a mix of quotation marks, which would require some contortions to ensure they are all escaped properly. In that case, a here document would be more appropriate then the `-c` option (although this presents its own issues if the code to run needs to read from standard input.)

```
python << EOF
from module import func
try:
  func()
except ValueError:
  pass
EOF
```

Comment: Indeed, this works. Makes me feel slightly stupid... well.. +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also enter the script to be executed interactively like this:

```
$ cat -- | python
<code here>
<code here>
<code here>
<press Ctrl-D>
```

and Python will run what you entered, for example:

```
~$ cat -- | python
from module import func
try:
  func()
except ValueError:
  pass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named module
```

Comment: That is not what I need, but still interesting.

Comment: I've changed the example to your code; maybe then it's what you need.

Comment: The `cat` is unnecessary. You could do `python <<-SCRIPT`, using a heredoc.

Comment: @kojiro: true, but it's not shorter, so the reverse logic also holds.

Comment: It's not shorter, but it's fewer processes.

Comment: Like that matters in 99.9% of the cases.

Comment: @ErikAllik isn't your example interactive? I need it inside a script.

Comment: If inside of script, then you are right; I missed that bit.