# Python: "Try" inside shortened for...loop

Tags: python, loops, try-catch, shortcut

Assume I'd like to convert a list of strings to integer, but it cannot be done for all elements.

I know this works:

```
a = ['2.0','3.0','4.0','5.0','Cherry']
b = []

for k in a:
    try:
        int(k)
        b.append(int(k))
    except:
        pass

print b
> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But is there also a shorter way of doing this? I thought about something like:

```
b = [try int(k) for k in a]
```

This may sound like a silly question since I do have a working solution, but I have often been shown shorter ways of doing the same thing and always appreciated this kind of help. I am using Python 2.7

Thanks!

Edit: sorry, I was also talking about floating point. I just changed my example data

Comment: At the very least you can omit the standalone redundant `int(k)`.

Comment: Never, ever, ever do a blank `except`, and especially never ever ever do that only to `pass`.

Comment: Edit: my code doesn't work without the except. It raises an error that the following code block was unindented?

Comment: Have you found your solution yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to use `try/except` clauses inside **List Comprehensions** but this could help:

```
a = ['2','3','4','5','Cherry']
print [int(x) for x in a if x.isdigit()]
```

Output:

```
['2', '3', '4', '5']
```

> **Update (as the question was updated):**

This could help but I don't know how good/accurate is to use it:

```
a = ['2.0','3.0','4.0','5.0', '44545.45', 'Cherry']

[float(x) for x in a if x.split('.')[0].isdigit() and x.split('.')[1].isdigit()]
```

Output:

```
[2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 44545.45]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[int(x) for x in a if x.isdigit()]` since OP wants a list of integers.

Comment: Note that this will not work for negative numbers, number with an explicit `+` such as `'+123'`, etc.

Comment: This would be a perfect solution, but I should have mentioned that the list also contains floating point numbers. Does a function like "x.isstr()" exist? I could then add "if not x.isstr()"

Comment: @offeltoffel, yeah you should. Now every answer is based on integers.

Comment: it seems that for updated answer it won't work. You can't do int('2.0').

Comment: @Andrey: yes, I didn't know that either, so it didn't seem important to me - my fault. But still I have learned something new and with these answers I was able to improve my solution

Comment: @offeltoffel I've updated my answer. And as I mention, I don't know how accurate it is, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
def is_number(k):
    try:
        float(k)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

[int(float(k)) for k in a if is_number(k)]
```

Comment: `'33'` is not an instance of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compress `try-except` into one line then i think answer is **NO** and it is answered at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524853/python-try-statement-single-line).
I would go with mix of `regex` and `isinstance` check-It captures all number types e.g. float, long, int and complex-

```
>>>a=['2', '3', '4', '5', 'Cherry', '23.3', '-3']
>>>filter(bool,[i if isinstance(eval(i),(int, long, float, complex)) else None for i in filter(lambda x: re.findall(r'[-+]?\d+[\.]?\d*',x),a)])
>>>['2', '3', '4', '5', '23.3', '-3']
```

If you want to capture only `floats`-

```
>>>filter (bool,[i if isinstance(eval(i),float) else None for i in filter(lambda x: re.findall(r'[-+]?\d+[\.]?\d*',x),a)])
>>>['23.3']
```

If you want to capture only `int`-

```
>>>filter (bool,[i if isinstance(eval(i),int) else None for i in filter(lambda x: re.findall(r'[-+]?\d+[\.]?\d*',x),a)])
>>>['2', '3', '4', '5', '-3']
```