# Define with statement that automatically includes try and except

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, with-statement

Is it possible to define an own `with` statement which automatically includes try...except error handling?
For example, it would be neat to have a shorthand for this:

```
with Do_Something():
    try:
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

...that looks like this:

```
with Try_Something():
    ...
```

How can we include the try...except behaviour into the following MWE class?

```
class Do_Something():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        print('Starting...')
        # invoke "try" somewhere here?
        return(self)

    def __exit__(self, except_type, except_value, tb):
        # invoke "except" somewhere here?
```

Comment: The `__exit__()` methods allows exception handling. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__) for details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling exceptions inside context managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483359/handling-exceptions-inside-context-managers)

Comment: @Corralien: the link was helpful, but it deals with a far more specific problem. It does not fully answer the question stated here as I do not want to handle errors in a certain way, I want to reproduce the default output of try...except. I.e., the question boils down to how to output the traceback info provided by `__exit__` in a similar way as `str(e)` would do using the argument provided by `except` .

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__), if you want to suppress exceptions, `__exit__` should return `True`.

The args passed to `__exit__` will describe the exception in case you want to make conditional decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `with` natively comes with `try` under the hood and propagets the exceptions as arguments to `__exit__(...)`. So this could be a suitable solution:

```
import traceback
class Try_Something():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        print('Starting...')
        # invoke "try" somewhere here? -- No, "with" automatically invokes "try"
        return(self)

    def __exit__(self, except_type, except_value, tb):
        if not except_type:
            print('finished.')
        else:
            print('failed.')
            traceback.print_exc() # prints error similar to str(e) from the question
        return(True)
```

I did not find a solution that goes without `import traceback`. Please comment if there is a way to directly print the traceback info using the provided arguments without additional modules.