# One-Line Exception Handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

In Python, it is possible to use one-liners to set values with special conditions (such as defaults or conditions) in a simple, intuitive way.

```
result = 0 or "Does not exist."  # "Does not exist."

result = "Found user!" if user in user_list else "User not found."
```

Is it possible to write a similar statement that catches exceptions?

```
from json import loads

result = loads('{"value": true}') or "Oh no, explosions occurred!"
# {'value': True}

result = loads(None) or "Oh no, explosions occurred!"
# "Oh no, explosions occurred!" is desired, but a TypeError is raised.
```

Comment: Why not put the standard `try..except` into the function?

Comment: @Slayer Interestingly, Python will actually use a string (or any other object, in fact) as an "alternate" for `or`. `0 or "Does not exist."` will return `"Does not exist."`. (I have tested it.)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I do not have access to the internals of the `divide_one_by` function - assume that it is defined in a separate module which I am using as a dependency.

Comment: @2Cubed: no reason to be surprised. `0 OR x` evaluates to `x` for all values of `x`, except`0` itself.

Comment: So write a wrapper function, perhaps?

Comment: @RadLexus - It evaluates to `x` when `x` is `0` as well. It'll simply be `0`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: does that not evaluate to `False` instead? (Testing..) Oh I see it indeed does not. :) `print 0 or False` *does*, though, proving my point on *anything* for `x`. Even 0.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Good idea. Thanks!

Comment: There is a [PEP](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/#proposal) to add something like this, but it hasn't been accepted yet.

Comment: suppress maybe useful for some cases https://stackoverflow.com/a/52020518/8583496

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is not possible to do a one-line exception-handling statement in python. One could write a function to do this.

```
def safe_execute(default, exception, function, *args):
    try:
        return function(*args)
    except exception:
        return default
```

Example usage:

```
from json import loads
safe_execute("Oh no, explosions occurred!", TypeError, loads, None)
# Returns "Oh no, explosions occurred!"
safe_execute("Huh?", TypeError, int, "10")
#Returns 10
```

Multiple arguments are supported

```
from operator import div
safe_execute(
    "Divsion by zero is invalid.",
    ZeroDivisionError,
    div, 1, 0
)
# Returns "Divsion by zero is invalid."

safe_execute(
    "Divsion by zero is invalid.",
    ZeroDivisionError,
    div, 1, 1
)
# Returns 1.
```

The error-catching process may still be interrupted:

```
from time import sleep
safe_execute(
    "Panic!",
    Exception,
    sleep, 8
)
# Ctrl-c will raise a KeyboardInterrupt

from sys import exit
safe_execute("Failed to exit!", Exception, exit)
# Exits the Python interpreter
```

If this behavior is undesired, use `BaseException`:

```
from time import sleep
safe_execute("interrupted",
             BaseException,
             sleep, 8)
#Pressing Ctrl-c will return "interrupted"
from sys import exit
safe_execute("Naughty little program!",
             BaseException,
             exit)
#Returns "Naughty little program!"
```

Comment: You have a great suggestion. I am trying to create a similar workaround for my problem but the code is unable to work. I have detailed the problem at https://stackoverflow.com/q/56916092/6701627. I will be thankful if you could check the problem and provide some suggestion on it.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible in one line using exec:

```
parse_float = lambda x, y=exec("def f(s):\n try:\n  return float(s)\n except:  return None"): f(x)
```

Comment: yeah but that's so horribly unpythonic... it's like putting an image of a website on a website instead of the actual html itself

Answer (score 3):

You can use `contextlib` to `suppress` exceptions. If you like to live dangerously you could suppress `BaseException`, which would suppress all builtin exceptions (probably a bad idea). Or you could pick a safe one relevant to your code, like `TypeError`.

examples:

```
from contextlib import suppress

# this will execute right along
with suppress(BaseException): fhasldjkfhsa345315

# even raising an Exception will fly just fine
with suppress(BaseException): raise NameError

# correct code will execute just fine
x=5
with suppress(BaseException): x+=2
print(x) # prints 7

# and in your example:
from json import loads
pleasure = suppress(TypeError) # so each line rolls off the tongue :)

with pleasure: result = loads('{"value": True}')
print(result) # prints {'value': True}

with pleasure: result = loads(None)
print(result) # prints {'value': True} because result never changed
```

Answer (score 1):

pppery's answer is a more complete solution, but I prefer a more terse (and simpler) approach:

```
def maybe(function):
    try:
        return function()
    except:
        return None
```

With this utility, we can do stuff like this:

```
# Instead of doing this
last_item = self.stock.items[-1] if self.stock and self.stock.items else None

# It can be done like this
last_item = maybe(lambda: self.stock.items[-1])
```

Now, for cases when the default value isn't None (like on the question's example), we can add the OR operator safely:

```
result = maybe(lambda: loads('{"value": true}')) or 'Oh no, explosions occurred!'
```

It's a readable and easy solution to handle expected exceptions. I wish Python had something similar natively. As Fnord noted in his answer, the closest solution Python has is *contextlib.suppress*, but it has 2 limitations:

1. It forces you to specify the exception type (safe, but usually unnecessary).
2. It doesn't resolve to a value (since the *with* statement has no return), which prevents you from using the result inside another expression. Notice that using *suppress* forces you to initialize *result* with the default string in a separate line.