# write try and except in a single line in python

Tags: python, lambda, try-catch, export-to-csv

I have a list of addresses and latitude,longitudes which I am printing from a text file. It has a few 0's so I am using `try` and `except` blocks.

Now I want to save the output to a CSV file and I am trying this code:

```
with open("qwe.txt",'r') as fp, open("qwert.txt",'w') as fr:
    for line in fp:
        #try:
            g= geocoder.google(line)
            #print(g.address,g.latlng)
       # except:
            #print(0,0)
            writer = csv.writer(fr, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerows(zip(g.address,g.latlng))

fp.close()
```

but the loop is exiting when there is 0 occurence. I want to write `try` and `catch` on a single line so that I can print the output to a CSV.

I tried using `lambda` but looks like `lamda` doesn't work for `try` and `except`.

Comment: Your title hardly seems to match your question. Which one is the real question?

Comment: hello @jdgregson sorry for the ambiguity, I have edited the post and its purpose now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: try statement in a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524853/python-try-statement-in-a-single-line)

Comment: I could write it in a different way. I wrote a loop to print it to csv inside try block and left except to print 0's. In my case, I dont want to have 0's in my csv. This worked for me in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Please refer to this SO question: [Python: try statement in a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524853/python-try-statement-in-a-single-line)

> There is no way to compress a `try`/`except` block onto a single line in
>   Python.